# MS Outlook does not synchronize my emails from Outlook.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook.com

I am having issues with my Outlook.com email account. Recently I started to use MS Outlook and when I complete the process of adding my Outlook.com account it synchronizes only very old emails that I have.

On the email client for Windows 10, the same account synchronizes perfectly.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you verified your accessing the same account in both cases?  When you say "old emails' how old specifically?

Comment: Yes, it is the same outlook account. And the emails are from 5 years ago

Comment: Did you configured the account within Outlook for POP3 or IMAP.  Have you let Outlook download all your emails?  5 years of data might take awhile to synchronize.

Comment: No idea, for both cases It does automatically

Comment: Does what automatically, the user, chooses pop3 or imap.  What type of data file .OST or .PST?  Look "I don't know" to this question isn't an acceptable answer.